# Programmatically selecting an Item in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, listbox

I have three `ListBoxes` (**CompanyName**, **Representative** & **QuoteNumber**) and I load data from my WCF client, into the *CompanyName* list box using the method below:

```
private async Task LoadCompanies()
{
    using (TruckServiceClient client = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        var companies = await client.GetCompaniesAsync();
        foreach (var company in companies)
            lbxCompanyName.Items.Add(new ListBoxViewItem<Company>(company));
    }
}
```

Now in the coding below I allow myself to select the **Company Name** in the `lbxCompanyName` ListBox and then viewing the **Representatives** that belongs to that Company in my `lbxRepresentative` ListBox.

```
private void lbxCompanyName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var company = (ListBoxViewItem<Company>)lbxCompanyName.SelectedItem; //Changing this line to auto select an Item for me
    foreach (var rep in company.Item.Represetatives)
        lbxRepresentatives.Items.Add(new ListBoxViewItem<Represetative>(rep));
}
```

What I want to achieve is to auto/programmatically select the name, let's say "Josh", from the ***CompanyName*** ListBox. How would I go about doing this with the coding that I have now?

Basically I want to hide my listboxes and let my program select everything for me.

Comment: Why don't you use data binding for this? It's *much* easier that way and you can achieve this in WPF with almost zero code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Do you mean binding it in my XAML?

Comment: Yes, look for data binding tutorials. Then, suppose you have a `Company` class with a `IList<Person> Representatives` property, and a `IList<Company> Companies` property in your data context. You could bind the companies list box as `Items="{Binding Companies}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` and the representative list box as `Items="{Binding Companies/Representatives}"`. Job done :-)

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski -Thanks for all the effort man ;). I just wan't to know, how will I be able to select a **specific** company name from the data binding? I am not so clued up with XAML, but I will go and do some research on it now.

Comment: That too can be done with bindings... `SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCompany, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purposes I solved my issue by setting my first two ListBoxes (CompanyName, Representative)`SelectedIndex` to 0 and then using the coding below for my last ListBox (QuoteNumber) to select the last inserted row in my QuoteNumber listbox.

```
    if (lbxQuoteNumber.Items.Count > -1)
        lbxQuoteNumber.SelectedIndex = lbxQuoteNumber.Items.Count - 1;
```

Thanks for all the help dudes! :)

Answer (score 1):

With [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms750612(v=vs.100).aspx) you can bind the ItemsSource and [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then you can just assign the SelectedItem in code behind
You most likely will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

And you can populate Representative with binding
But what you have is strange - you just keep added Represetatives with each SelectionChanged